# Using residuals from linear regression for normality testing for ANOVA

Tags: regression, residuals, normality-assumption

For testing the assumption of normality of residuals for ANOVA, can the residuals from linear regression be used instead of the residuals from GLM?

Comment: What do you mean by testing the residuals from GLM when you’re doing ANOVA? What generalized linear model would you be fitting?

Comment: I noticed that for obtaining the residuals for testing the normality assumption for ANOVA,people use GLM in SPPS and select the save residual option.Then they test the normality of that residual from GLM to determine whether they can perform ANOVA. My question is, instead of using the GLM to generate the residuals, can I use linear regression.

Comment: It sounds like you need to review generalized linear models and how to view ANOVA as a linear regression, as ANOVA is a generalized linear model with the identity function as the link function.

Comment: @Dave: GLM here probably is *General Linear Model*